# ¿Cómo hago una petición HTTP con Authorization: JWT <Token>?

Tags: javascript

La realidad es que no tengo mucha idea de cómo hacer una petición HTTP pero es que necesito obtener unos datos para los cuales preciso hacer una petición GET y autorizarme con un Token, mi pregunta es ¿qué es lo que debería incluir en el objeto options? y si alguien me pudiera dar una idea de como hacerlo en NodeJS lo agradecería.

Por ahora mi código es este:

```
import { get } from 'http';
    
const options = {
    hostname: 'url',//La url a consultar
    port: 443,
    path: '/api/v1.0/profesores',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'JWT token',//clave del token
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};
    
get(options, (res) => {
    //  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    //  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        const datos = JSON.parse(d);
        //process.stdout.write(datos);
        console.log(datos);
    });
    
}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "http". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Es:  hostname: url, que es el valor de la url, no 'url' porque entonces es un literal.

Comment: Estás usando Javascript o NodeJs?